# React: How do i trigger a function that contains a lifecycle method, from another component?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have two components Navbar and Modal.

The Navbar contains a function called `displayData()` that contains a lifecycle method called `componentDidMount()`.

So, In Modal Component I have a function that updates a data using FetchApi, On save of the data I need to trigger the `displayData()` function, I tried to pass it down as props, but it still doesn't get triggered

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated

**Navbar Code That contains the componentDidMount**

```
  //Displaying the Data
  componentDidMount() {
    this.displayData();
  }
  displayData() {
    fetch("/user")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          userArray: data
        });
      });
  }
```

**Modal Code where I need to trigger the `displayData()`**

```
 updateBtn = e => {
    fetch(`/user/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(newData)
    })
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.props.displayData(this); // This is where i'm trying to trigger the function
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

**Calling Modal from Navbar.** I'm Passing `displayData()` in the display as props

```
          <Modal
            data={this.state.username}
            dataone={this.state.email}
            id={this.state.id}
            close={this.closeModel}
            log={this.logChange}
            display={this.displayData}
          />
```

Comment: Can you post more code, as to how you are calling Modal component from Navbar component?

Comment: @tarzenchugh Yes,  I have updated the question

Comment: Yeah i removed that, It still doesn't work,  It shows this.props.displayData is not a function

Comment: You are not passing any data to displayData function and displayData function in Navbar component will be triggered anyhow as it is inside componentDidMount. You just need to call `<Modal />` component when you get the result form put call by using a state variable.

Comment: May i know why are you passing this as a parameter in that function and you are passing DisplayData function as dispaly in the props so try calling this.props.display() instead

Answer (score 0):

// Navbar Component

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = { isFetchComplete: false }
}

updateBtn = e => {
  fetch(`/user/${id}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(newData)
  })
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ isFetchComplete: true })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

{ this.state.isFetchComplete &&
  <Modal
  data={this.state.username}
  dataone={this.state.email}
  id={this.state.id}
  close={this.closeModel}
  log={this.logChange}
/>
}
```

// Modal Component

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {}
  this.displayData = this.displayData.bind(this)
}
//Displaying the Data
 componentDidMount() {
  this.displayData();
}
displayData() {
  fetch("/user")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        userArray: data
      });
    });
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Define `displayData()` using arrow function so that it's lexically binded to Navbar:

```
  displayData = () => {
    fetch("/user")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          userArray: data
        });
      });
  }
```

And then in your `Modal` code, you call `this.props.display` since you passed down the prop through: `display={this.displayData}`

```
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.props.display();
})
```